# How to access onion sites from php curl?

Tags: php, curl, tor

I use this code:

```
$this->curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://some-onion-site.onion");
    $contents = curl_exec($this->curl);
```

It's returns nothing instantly. Tor is working normally, and site is accessible from tor browser.
Edit: I've found that it can't resolve host ("Couldn't resolve host name" error).

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see what goes wrong

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've edited the question. It can't resolve the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found out that I need to set proxy type to CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
```

It works fine.